# for loop returning a number between 0 and 3 every cycle

Tags: node.js

I have this piece of code that runs a simple for loop:

```
const InvType = ["Hat", "Face", "FaceAccessory", "HairAccessory", "BackAccessory", "NeckAccessory", "FrontAccessory", "WaistAccessory", "Gear"]



var Prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var Inv = []

        for (let i = 0; i < InvType.length; i++) {
            https.get('https://inventory.roblox.com/v1/users/111138402/assets/collectibles?assetType=' + InvType[i] + '&sortOrder=Asc&limit=100', (resp) => {
                let data = '';

                // A chunk of data has been received.
                resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                    data += chunk;
                });

                // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
                resp.on('end', () => {
                    var arrayLength = JSON.parse(data).data.length;
                    for (var v = 0; v < arrayLength; v++) {
                        Inv.concat(JSON.parse(data).data[v])
                        console.log(i)
                    }
                    if (i >= 9) {
                        resolve(Inv)
                    }
                });

            }).on("error", (err) => {
                console.log("Error: " + err.message);
            });
        }
    })
```

I would like for this to resolve the promise once the Inv table has been filled, that way I do not move onto the next step of the code before the required data has been gathered.

for some reason the "i" variable in this loop always prints out as either 0, 1, or 3, and so the promise is never resolved. I am not the best at node, and do not know why this would be happening.

[image: example of output:]

^example of output

Comment: If I throw a pizza party and I order 9 pizzas from 9 different pizza places I want to start the party when **the 9th pizza arrives** not *when the pizza from the 9th place I called arrives*.  (Consider what happens if the 9th _HTTP get_ completes before the others.)  And certainly not when the 10th pizza arrives (your condition checks `i >= 9`  the 1st pizza has index 0, and the 10th pizza has index 9.)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new binding for `i` every iteration of the loop here:

```
for (let i = 0; i < InvType.length; i++) {
```

When the code runs, there are a bunch of different `i`s, not just one.

Since `i` never gets reassigned (except in the loop declaration), `i` is always 0 through 8, and never 9 inside the loop; once the declaration's `i` is 9, iteration stops. The loop body will always see an `i` between 0 and 8.

You could declare `i` outside the loop, or with `var`, but that wouldn't fix things because then `i` would be at its final value the first time the `if (i >= 9)` line is encountered.

Instead of messing with indicies, promisify `https.get` and use `Promise.all`, and flatten the response arrays with `.flat()`

```
const get = (url) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https
        .get(url, (resp) => {
            let data = '';
            resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });
            resp.on('end', () => {
                resolve(data);
            });
        })
        .on('error', reject);
});

const allProm = Promise.all(
    InvType.map(str => get('https://inventory.roblox.com/v1/users/111138402/assets/collectibles?assetType=' + str + '&sortOrder=Asc&limit=100'))
)
    .then(allResults =>
        allResults.map(resText => JSON.parse(resText).data).flat()
    )
    // .catch(handleErrors);
```

Comment: Saying "`i` is always 0 through 9, and never 9" may be a bit confusing.  `i` is never 9 inside the body of the loop because the loop condition is `i < InvType.length` and `InvType.length` is 9 ...therefore the condition to enter the loop body is `i < 9`.  (so `i >= 9` will never be true inside the body of the loop). I'm sure you realize this, but what you wrote doesn't come across clearly.

Comment: @CertainPerformance hey, I still am having a few issues even when using the solution you provided. In my understanding, The piece of code you provided defines get as a promise that makes https GET requests, then calls it once for every array entry using Promise.all. I have modified this, and put it into a asynchronous function that returns allProm. Then, within another function, I have defined “data” using var data = await getInv(). The problem I am having is that the array that data is defined as is still empty.

Comment: @me7474 The API you're using currently only gives empty arrays in the `data` property. For example: https://inventory.roblox.com/v1/users/111138402/assets/collectibles?assetType=WaistAccessory&sortOrder=Asc&limit=100%27 The same response is returned when anything else is substituted for `WaistAccessory`. As a result, the final output will also only be an empty array.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I completely forgot to swap out the ID of the person I was checking within the api, sorry! I will fix this when I get home.